# Access wordpress rest api from wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-rest-api

The question may seems dumb but i need to access wordpress's default rest api from my custom wordpress plugin so that i can modify further for my custom api endpoints and post data to a third party api.

I need to access and have all the data and functionalities of the existing rest api but i don't want to fetch data from database by querying again. Instead i want to call the rest api directly from plugin.

Now the problem it doesn't seems right to calling rest api from a plugin. If i want to avoid querying again from database is this a valid approach (calling rest api) or there are other better ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Wordpress Rest API HandBook, To modify Responses, You can use `register_rest_field` and `register_meta`.

More Details : [Modifying Responses](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/)

---

To Create an Endpoint you can use , `register_rest_route()`.

More Details : [Routes and Endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/)

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t difficult to make an internal REST API call, but it is a bit more involved than your normal WP_Query usage. Also, keep in mind that the parameters you pass to the REST API are not always the same as what you would pass to WP_Query. For example, the post_status query var would become status when making an API request.

```
<?php
  $request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/posts' );
  $request->set_query_params( [ 'per_page' => 12 ] );
  $response = rest_do_request( $request );
  $server = rest_get_server();
  $data = $server->response_to_data( 
  $response, false );
  $json = wp_json_encode( $data );
```

You can read more about in this [URL](https://wpscholar.com/blog/internal-wp-rest-api-calls/)